# Insert a new element to Trie when members are final

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, linked-list, trie

I need help with implementing the insert method which adds new child and siblings to the Trie. I saw many solutions. However, my problem is different because the class members insides the class are final so I  can't make reference to the next element when I'm traversing the tree. I searched a lot on the internet but seems I can't find any help. I've been struggling with this for two days. I will share my code below.

Below is all I have tried with the insert method.

```
public class TrieChildren extends AbstractTrieChildren {
    public TrieChildren(char c, AbstractTrie t, AbstractTrieChildren o) {
        super(c, t, o);
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractTrieChildren insertSorted(char character, AbstractTrie child) {

        AbstractTrieChildren current = this;
        AbstractTrieChildren newEntry = new TrieChildren(character, child, null);

        if (current.child == null) {
            current = newEntry;
        }


        while (current != null) {


            if (current.sibling == null) {

                current = newEntry;

            }
            current = current.sibling;


        }


        return current;


    }
```

As you can see in the code below members such as sibling are final.

```
public abstract class AbstractTrieChildren implements Iterable<AbstractTrieChildren> {
    /**
     * The label of the outgoing edge.
     */
    protected final char character;
    /**
     * The target of the outgoing edge.
     */
    protected final AbstractTrie child;
    /**
     * The reference to the next sibling or {@code null} if none.
     */
    protected final AbstractTrieChildren sibling;

    public AbstractTrieChildren(char character, AbstractTrie child, AbstractTrieChildren sibling) {
        this.character = character;
        this.child = child;
        this.sibling = sibling;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new labelled edge ({@link #character}, {@link #child}) to the <b>sorted</b> traversable linked list of siblings iff there is no such edge.
     * If an entry already exists, then this method leaves the list unchanged.
     *
     * @param character the label of the possibly new labelled edge to insert
     * @param child     the target trie of the possibly new labelled edge to insert
     * @return the new head (left-most node) of the <b>sorted</b> traversable linked sibling list
     */
    public abstract AbstractTrieChildren insertSorted(char character, AbstractTrie child);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Maybe I missed something silly

Comment: What I mean that "I can't make reference to the next element" is that I can't assign current.sibling to newEntry. Any help would be appreciated and if you don't know the answer then please upvote my question. Thanks

Comment: Could you motivate why you want them final? Also I dont think I followed your implementation because a Node in Trie is supposed to have Array of Children or Map of children (if you want to shrink the null values) and I dont see that on your implementation.

Comment: Hi. The sibling represent a LinkedList. In my implementation I don't want to use any Java api, so the sibling here replaces the Map. I know it becomes a lot easier using Map. The child of type AbstractTrie contains the String word and its children of type AbstractTrieChildren.

Comment: I guess that is good as a challenge but using linked list kinda kills the beauty of tries to me. If you dont want to use Map then Use Array. Regarding correctness of your implementation even if we agree on using linkedlist I expect to see char comparison because is that how how we chain Nodes in Trie. If a child with same char exists we want to use that one instead of creating new one.

Comment: The implementation of adding String to the Trie is existed in the implementation of AbstractTrie. I have also implemented a method locate() which determines if a char is existed in the Trie, so if char isn't existed,  the insertSorted method adds a new node with char, but I faced this problem of adding new elements if the class members are final, I should find a way of implementing it so that will keep the list sorted and immutable.